# Add metadata to Crawldb dump

Tags: nutch

I'm starting with Nutch (trunk version) and I'm spinning around the code without seeing something that seems obvious.

I want to extract the resource of every URLs crawled ( eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask ===> /question/ask ) expecting two results:
1. Post the information as an additional field to a Solr instance. I have solved this problem writing an IndexingFilter plugin and works perfectly.
2. Dumping this information as metadata when the next command it's thrown: bin/nutch readdb -dump crawldb

And at this second point it's where I'm stucked. Reading documentation and other examples it seems I have to use the CrawlDatum but I don't know in what class I have to modify in order to show this information when a dump is made.
Maybe someone knows where to touch in order to achieve this?

Some help will be appreciated!